# How can I get an object of a given type to be returned from HttpClient.get when requesting an abstract object?

Tags: angular, abstract, angular-httpclient

I have an abstract class:

```
export abstract class DataEntry {
  ...
  public abstract clone(): DataEntry;
}
```

and an actual class extending it:

```
export class Record extends DataEntry {
  ...
  public clone(): Record {
    return new Record(...);
  }
}
```

I have a service to request data from a database with an HttpClient's get method.

```
export class DbFacadeService {
  public static BASEURL: string = 'http://localhost:3000';
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }
  public readAll(): Observable<DataEntry[]> {
    return this._http.get<DataEntry[]>(`${DbFacadeService.BASEURL}`, { observe: 'response' })
                     .pipe(map((response: HttpResponse<DataEntry[]>) => response.body || []),
                           first());
  }
  ...
}
```

I periodically call this method from another service and store the results in a cache.

```
export class DataHandlerService {
  ...
  constructor(private _cache: Map<string, DataEntry>,
              private _dbFacade: DbFacadeService) {
    this._cache = new Map<string, DataEntry>([]);
    timer(0, 60000).subscribe(() => this.updateCache());
  }
  private updateCache(): void {
    this._dbFacade.readAll()
                  .subscribe((entries: DataEntry[]) => {
                               entries.forEach((entry: DataEntry) => this._cache.set(entry.id, entry);
                               ...
                             }
  }

  public readEntry(id: string): DataEntry | undefined {
    return this._cache.get(entryId);
  }
}
```

And then I'll call this method from my component, which displays the form for the user to edit:

```
export abstract class EditorComponent<T extends DataEntry> implements OnInit {
  ...
  public dataEntry: T | undefined;
  // can't create object of abstract DataEntry so I pass this responsibility to the actual class.
  protected abstract get _defaultValue(): T;
  public abstract entryForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute,
              private _router: Router,
              private _dataHandler: DataHandlerService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._route.paramMap.subscribe((parameters: ParamMap) => this.init(parameters));
  }
  private init(parameters: ParamMap): void {
    const entryId: string | undefined = parameters.get('id') || undefined;
    if (!entryId) {
      // if no id in url, "create new object" was called, otherwise "edit existing object".
      this.dataEntry = this._defaultValue;
      return;
    }

    const entry: T | undefined = this._dataHandler.readEntry(entryId)?.clone() as T;
    if (!entry) {
      // navigate to an error page and display entry not found error
      this._router.navigate(['/error', '404.1']);
    }

    this.dataEntry = entry;
    this.entryForm.patchValue(this.dataEntry!);
  }
}
```

And then I extend from this abstract class in my actual component to display the specific form for a specific DataEntry subclass.

```
export class RecordEditorComponent extends EditorComponent<Record> {
  ...
  protected get _defaultValue(): Record { return new Record(...); }
  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute,
              router: Router,
              dataHandler: DataHandlerService,
              formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    super(route, router, dataHandler);

    this.entryForm = formBuilder.group(...);
  }
}
```

To my surprise I had to learn that `this._http.get<DataEntry[]>(...)` does not actually return an observable with objects of the type given as type parameter but simply whatever was returned from the http call. Meaning, whatever I stored in the cache wasn't actually a `DataEntry`, much less a `Record` and thus did not contain the `clone` method. While it compiles (I guess the only reason for the type argument in the `HttpClient` only serves that purpose?) I receive a runtime exception as I cannot call `undefined`, i.e. the non-existing `clone` method.

I've tried to cast the response of the http call but this won't create an actual `DataEntry` object either:

```
.pipe(map((response: HttpResponse<DataEntry[]>) =>
            response.body?.map((entry: any) => entry as DataEntry) || [])
```

I've read that one must do the conversion manually in order to achieve this, i.e.:

```
.pipe(map((response: HttpResponse<DataEntry[]>) =>
            response.body?.map((entry: any) => new DataEntry(...)) || [])
```

However, I cannot create a new object of an abstract class. The `DataHandlerService` is oblivious as to what it's actually storing there, just that the objects are derived from `DataEntry`, so I can't create anything there as well (to my knowledge). The only thing I can think of is create an actual object from the given data instead of calling the `clone` method, but I would like to have the objects of the proper type already stored in the cache. I was thinking about a static creation method in the abstract `DataEntry` class but I can't make a static method abstract. I also couldn't find out how to create a new object of a dynamically given type.

So, is there a way to get objects of the actual `Record` (or whatever else will be derived from `DataEntry` in the future) in my cache? I couldn't find a way to dynamically create an object of a given type, so do I have to accept that whatever is in the cache is just `any` and I have to create the objects every time I call the cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can easily hydrate your data when it is used, but it looks hard to be able to do it in your cache as from what we see, there is no way for your cache to know the type of entity it has received.

You'll be able to do it using your abstract component, by defining an abstract property which should have the contructor to use. Exactly like you do with your default.

```
export abstract class EditorComponent<T extends DataEntry> implements OnInit {
  ...
  public dataEntry: T | undefined;
  // can't create object of abstract DataEntry so I pass this responsibility to the actual class.
  protected abstract get _defaultValue(): T;
  protected abstract get _entityConstructor(): Constructor<T>;
  public abstract entryForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute,
              private _router: Router,
              private _dataHandler: DataHandlerService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._route.paramMap.subscribe((parameters: ParamMap) => this.init(parameters));
  }
  private init(parameters: ParamMap): void {
    const entryId: string | undefined = parameters.get('id') || undefined;
    if (!entryId) {
      // if no id in url, "create new object" was called, otherwise "edit existing object".
      this.dataEntry = this._defaultValue;
      return;
    }

    const entry: T | undefined = new this._entityConstructor(this._dataHandler.readEntry(entryId)).clone() as T;
    if (!entry) {
      // navigate to an error page and display entry not found error
      this._router.navigate(['/error', '404.1']);
    }

    this.dataEntry = entry;
    this.entryForm.patchValue(this.dataEntry!);
  }
}
```

If you really wanted to have your hydrated entities inside your cache, you'd need to have some way to detect the class of each element, either by the value of a property which would be easiest or by the presence of exclusive properties.

You could have some list of available Models:

```
const models = {MyModel:MyModelClass};
// In your caching mecanic
entries.forEach((entry: DataEntry) => this._cache.set(entry.id, models [entry.type]?models [entry.type](entry):entry);
```

The problem with having it in the cache is that it will still return `DataEntry` typed elements. You would have to hint it to the `readEntry` function.

We have already tackled the problem on our side, but we had one service per model, instead of having a generic one. That way components did not need to care about anything, they just used the appropriate service. This would also allow you more fine-grained caching mechanics, instead of having a big pool. You'd have one for each model. Their caching mecanics could even be tweeked differently depending on their type, like some type of objects are certinaly created/updated less often.

Comment: I had specific database services before I reworked the whole thing to use Observables instead of Promises, but realized most of my pages are very similar and the database services basically all did the same thing with a different request url. The models were all very similar as well, and some of the pages were already generic, only switching the databse url via a dataType property. That's why I went for a generic approach. It just made sense to me, but then again, I assumed I'd get the proper objects from the http client.

Comment: As for the cache not knowing what it has received, that's fine, as long as it receives the proper objects, which imo it already should from the http request, but in reality it doesn't. It's also fine if it stores `DataEntry`, as long as the derived properties won't get dropped. In fact, that what I assumed would happen. I have `DataEntry` objects in my cache, which I then cast to whatever it really is (`Record` in this case).

Comment: This actually does look promising. I already have a dataType property in my `Record` class for the different kinds of data entries I manage in the generic pages (i.e. they're all a list of specific `Record`s, where I can add, edit, remove them). The only unfortunate thing is that my services are in the shared module while the `Record` model is in my record module, so I'll have to reanrrange this, which I'm not fond of, but alas, "you'll have to die one death" as we say in German.

Comment: And your last comment points to the reason why you keep one service per model :) Quite frankly, our services are for the most part empty, they just extend the abstract generic service. The only prop they must have is the URL and the constructor to hydrate properly.

Comment: Yeah. I didn't like the `Record` model in the shared module tbh. So I played around with the constructor methods in the `EditorComponent` and ended up replacing the clone method with with a static `from(record Record)` method but it's a complex object I need a deep copy of so I have to extend several classes with their own static method and I'm not a fan.

Comment: The issue with a specific database service for each `DataEntry` subclass is that I'd like to keep a single centralized `DataHandler` handling the cache instead of having to create a specified cache class for each `DataEntry` as well and then I'd just end up with the same issue, the `DataHandler` in the shared module requiring knowledge of the specified database service in the `RecordModule`. It would be so nice if the HttpClient would just return the object of the type parameter...

Comment: It does return the Object, just not the class. Also types are just for the developper, they are not part of the final javascript. The DataHandler can still be used by the asbtracted service if you want to stay with the centralized cache...

Comment: That's what I mean with "of the type parameter". But in that case I would have to control the database service from the component, won't I? Passing it to the data handler and setting the page specific values for the generic pages. I'd prefer if the component was completely separate of the database service, only accessing the data via the data handler.

Comment: I've realized it will not be possible with my current application logic. The only thing I can do is the first option you mentioned in your answer as the constructor selection is runtime based but the database requests are independent of that.

Comment: So I'm currently changing my application logic after looking into the strategy pattern and using that in combination with a `LoadingStrategistService`, which contains a list of these strategies I can add into from my component. I've also outsourced the interval of database requests and added an observable. So when the interval hits, the strategist calls `.next()` on the observable for every strategy in its list. The data handler now only registers to that observable receiving type and constructor method and uses that for the actual database request.

Comment: I will accept your answer as it basically says it's not possible with my current logic in the cache itself but only in the component and pushed me onto the right track... well, hopefully the right one. If this doesn't work I'll go with your suggestion to do it in the component itself. Thank you.

Comment: I never said it was not possible to do it in the cache, I've stated 2 options to be able to do so... Only in my comments did I say I thought it was not the best idea.

Comment: You're right. I should have stated this differently.